# partition a number range based on a size and then find the start of a partition for a given number in that range

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Sorry if this question has been asked before but I couldn't find a good match for what I am trying to do.

I am looking for an algorithm to do the below in C# (or relevant LINQ extensions).

Given a number within a set of numbers (e.g. `56 of 1 to 245`) not excluding any numbers
and a partition size (e.g. `10`)
I want to find the starting number for the partition that the given number is in.

Example: 
Searching for the starting page of 56.

```
1-10
11-20
21-30
31-40
41-50 
51-60 <-- 56 is in the partition starting with 51
..
231-240
241-245
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int page = 56;
int partition_size = 10;

int starting_number = (page / partition_size) * partition_size + 1;
```

Comment: Ok so if I am looking at that right its (56/10) = 5.6 but as an int it is 5. Then (5 * 10) + 1 = 51. Looks nice and easy, and there I was confusing myself. Thanks

Comment: @Pricey When you divide integers the result is always an integer so yes

Comment: I just recently found out that this does not work as intended for the last number in a partition, i.e. 20 / 10 * 10 + 1 = 21 so got to be careful of that.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.Net there is a Math function called DivRem, which divides two real numbers and gives the remainder.  This is essentially the same as the other solution, but it expands your horizons when you use built in Math functions.

```
        Dim startingindex, inputparam, delta As Integer
        delta = 10
        inputparam = 56
        startingindex = inputparam - Math.DivRem(inputparam, delta, startingindex)
```

Result is: startingindex = 51